# Why use sealed instead of static on a class?

Tags: c#, static-access, msdn

Our system has several utility classes.

Some people on our team use (A) a class with all-static methods and a private constructor.

Others use (B) a class with all-static methods (these the juniors).

On code analysis, (A) and (B) raise warning [CA1052](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182168.aspx), which recommends marking the class as sealed.

Included in the MSDN documentation there is the following advice:

> If you are targeting .NET Framework 2.0 or earlier, a better approach is to mark the type as static.

Why does this make any sense? I would have thought the opposite; AFAIK, previous to 2.0 there was no way to mark a class as static.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MSDN page is wrong; it should say "later" not "earlier".  `static` classes were introduced in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a good number of utility classes in the pre-2.0 era which have all `static` methods and a `private` default constructor to make it non-instantiable.  Even back then though, that class should have been `sealed`.

2.0 and later, simply mark the class as `static` and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

The CA1052 warning is a little off-target.  You should declare classes that contain only static members as static rather than sealed.  Classes declared static are implicitly sealed.